# Number of ways to pick 16 people and place them in 11 non-empty groups. Details follow...

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: How many ways can 16 people be placed in 11 groups, where...

- Groups 1 through 10 each have exactly 1 person
- Group 11 has exactly 6 people
- The order of the 6 players in group 11 does not matter (i.e. [Bob, Jim, Tim, Matt, Bill, Rob] in group 11 is equivalent to [Matt, Rob, Bob, Tim, Jim, Bill] in group 11 and should *not* be counted twice)...group 11 is the "catch all" for players not assigned to any of groups 1 through 10.

EDIT

- Alicia in Group 1 and Beti in Group 2 <> Beti in Group 1 and Alicia in 2

Comment: You can choose who goes into Group 1 in 16 ways, then you can choose who goes into Group 2 in 15 ways and so on down to 7 ways for who goes into Group 10. So total $\frac{16!}{6!}=29059430400$.

Comment: From the wording, it looks as if groups are *labelled*. Is Alicia in Group 1 and Beti in Group 2 different from Beti in Group 1 and Alicia in 2?

Comment: Alicia in Group 1 and Beti in Group 2 <> Beti in Group 1 and Alicia in 2

Answer (score 3):

There are $16\choose 6$ ways to pick the members of group $11$. There are $10!$ ways to permute the remaining ten persons to ten groups.
So ...
$$ {16\choose 6}\cdot 10!=\frac{16!}{10!6!}\cdot 10!=\frac{16!}{6!}$$

The last expression suggests a different approach: There are $16!$ ways to arrange the 16 people in a line. By grouping the last six into one group, we identify $6!$ of these arrangements. Hence the total count is (again)  $\frac{16!}{6!}$.